# "Bridging" Reactor's Flux from gRPC StreamObserver

Tags: java, grpc, project-reactor, grpc-java

I want to create a [Reactor Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) from a [gRPC StreamObserver](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.html). This needs to be done as long as StreamObserver does not implement the respective interfaces natively (see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter/issues/3)).

What I came up with is roughly like the following:

```
final StreamObserver<ProtoResponse>[] streamObserverArray = new  StreamObserver[1];
Flux<Response> myFlux Flux.create(sink -> streamObserverArray[0] = new StreamObserver<ProtoResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(ProtoResponse value) {
            final Response response = convertFromProto(value);
            sink.next(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            sink.error(throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            sink.complete();
        }
    });
myFlux
    .doOnError(throwable -> {/* actual logic in here */}) //
    .doOnComplete(() -> {/* actual logic in here */}) //
    .doOnCancel(() -> {/* actual logic in here */}) //
    .parallel() //
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) //
    .doOnNext(/* actual heavy lifting logic in here */) //
    .map(/* ... */) //
    .sequential() //
    .doOnNext(/* ...*/) //
    .subscribe(); // needed to start the actual processing of the events on this Flux

MyGrpcService.newStub(channel).getResponses(protoRequest, streamObserverArray[0]);
```

The main idea why I want to use Reactor here is to distribute the "heavy lifting work" onto several threads in parallel and not do that on the gRPC request threads.

I see several problems with the approach as it is done above:

- I really don't like the workaround with the `StreamObserver[]` array
- I need to create the complete flux first because if I don't finish it off with `.subscribe()` first, the `StreamObserver` might be `null` when gRPC starts communicating (aka race condition).
- I am not sure if backpressure works the way it is intended (although this is currently not my main concern).

So my questions would be:
What is the best/preferred way to bridge from a gRPC StreamObserver to a Reactor Flux? Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more fiddling around and understanding the whole reactive stuff a bit better, I came up with the following solution:

```
/**
* Bridge the StreamObserver from gRPC to the Publisher from the reactive world.
*/
public class StreamObserverPublisher implements Publisher<Long>, StreamObserver<Long> {

    private Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber;

    @Override
    public void onNext(Long l) {
        subscriber.onNext(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        subscriber.onError(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        this.subscriber.onSubscribe(new BaseSubscriber() {});
    }
}

// and somewhere else in the code
StreamObserverPublisher streamObserverPublisher = new StreamObserverPublisher();
Flux<Long> longFlux = Flux.from(streamObserverPublisher);
longFlux.subscribe(...); // must be done before executing the gRPC request
MyGrpcService.newStub(channel).getResponses(protoRequest, streamObserverPublisher);
```

Comment: hi, I just want to know why longFlux.subscribe() has to happen before executing the gRPC request. Thanks.

Comment: @trjade: I really don't remember, that was almost three years ago and, as mentioned in the other answer, we have replaced our hand-rolled solution with the reactive-grpc library by Salesforce.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays there's an easier solution:

https://github.com/salesforce/reactive-grpc.

It supports bridging gRPC to both Reactor and RxJava 2.

Comment: Thanks for putting this here. We have switched to using that library in all our products by now and are happy with it!